# New style csproj automatically shows references to System.Drawing, FileSystem, etc

Tags: c#, .net, csproj

I have changed over a class library of mine to be the new csproj style and now I see under `Assemblies` there are some automatically added references that I can't remove. Where do these come from and why are they there?

Screenshot example:

[image]

Just a note, this isn't causing any issues. Just seems weird and was curious to know why these are added. I googled the issue and couldn't find anything

Comment: What new csproj style are you referring to?

Comment: This comes from a build rule in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targets, search for "$(DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences)" to find it.  Yes, pretty weirdo choices.  Editing the .targets file would be a workaround, but maybe not such a good idea with updates being so frequent.

Comment: ah awesome thanks. That is it! I don't plan to edit the file was just wondering if I was doing something wrong. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These automatic references have been added to reduce size of the csproj files so they are easier to read and edit and don't need special conditional references when multi-targeting between .net standard/core and .net framework.

The decision and discussions about which references to add (see pull requests to the dotnet/sdk GitHub repos) was based on:

- Which references are added by other existing templates by default (.net class library, web apps etc.)
- Which libraries are needed so the a similar set of types as in .net standard is available by default without needing to edit the project file.
- What types are commonly used (http-related types, drawing primitives etc.)

Since references aren't emitted into the built assembly if no types from the reference are used, they do not impact the built product.